# How to make a a arrow script in gnuplot from a series of grepped data from an text file

Tags: gnuplot

My data file is:

## ============

```
     This is your required output
Range:  -42.3732  666.3634eV  Yi, Yf > DATA-point FIX:  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000   x LIST   0.0000
DATA-point FIX:  0.5000 0.0000 0.0000   x LIST   0.5000
DATA-point FIX:  0.7500 0.3750 0.2641   x LIST   1.0224
DATA-point FIX:  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000   x LIST   1.9015
DATA-point FIX:  0.3750 0.3750 0.5282   x LIST   2.6500
DATA-point FIX:  0.5000 0.5000 0.3522   x LIST   2.8995
DATA-point FIX:  0.0000 0.0000 0.0000   x LIST   3.6895
DATA-point FIX:  0.5000 0.0000 0.3522   x LIST   4.3010
DATA-point FIX:  0.6250 0.2500 0.4402   x LIST   4.5941
DATA-point FIX:  0.7500 0.2500 0.3522   x LIST   4.7470
DATA-point FIX:  0.5000 0.5000 0.3522   x LIST   5.1005
DATA-point FIX:  0.5000 0.2500 0.5282   x LIST   5.4063

done junk has written below this part
```

## ========

I want to set the number

```
`-42.3732 and 666.3634 as y-axis limit`
```

and then want to draw the arrow from

```
 Xi, Yi to Xi, Yi nohead
```

where Xi is a variable number and depends on the data file but I can grep it using

```
 grep LIST data.dat |  awk '{print $NF}'
```

and

```
Yi and Yf are the y-axis limit as mentioned above but changes according to data file so these numbers are not the one that I mention here).
```

I want to draw arrows on each of these point from Xi, Yi to Xi, Yf in my gnu script.

I have some idea that it can be done if we store the above data in a variable form and the do like this

```
set VARIABLE
```

where variable is like this

```
VARIABLE=`arrow from Xi,Yi to Xi,Yf nohead ; set`
```

and for the next part I want to label each Xi at x-axis with some letter say

```
X, Y, Z, .....
```

Could you please advise me how I can manage it in gnuplot?

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example, or scetch of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I also am unsure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want to draw arrows between points whose coordinates come from a file you might be better off using `plot ... with vectors` than `set arrow`.

Comment: in your data I see 4 columns of numbers. The last one apparently is `xi`. Which one is `yi` and which one is `yf`? What is `fi`? It's also not clear to me. Is this `>` sign in your data above correct or a mistake?

Comment: if you are still interested in an answer it would be good to clarify. If you found an answer it would be good to post your solution as answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Dear All,  I respect all of your replies.  I am sorry I could not replied you all well in time. I am on long leaves and will come back on Monday.

Comment: Dear all, thank you very much for keeping this post open. It was a long festival holidays so I today joined my work place. below is more explained query.

Comment: Whatever the main text I have posted is having all original symbols.                               A.   The number in the second  line "-42.3732  666.3634eV  Yi, Yf " defines the Y-axis minimum (-42.3732) and Y-axis maximum (666.3634). so in gnu script Y-axis should be like that it starts at and -42.3732  end at 666.3634.

Comment: B.  next in the same script I want to  draw arrow with nohead from Xi, Yi to Xi, Yi nohead
where Yi and Yf are from my previous comment and Xi is the number 
where Xi is a variable and depends on the data.dat (each new file will have new XI) and it can be grepped using (on terminal)
cat  data.dat | grep LIST |  awk '{print $NF}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still not clear to me from your description where to get which values.

My understanding is the following:
You have one (or several?) files which have the structure which you gave (whereas the structure of the second line with `>` and the data after this looks strange to me).
As I understand, the awk-command extracts the value of the last token (column) in a line.
So, I assume `xi` is the last value of each line. In line 2, `xi` would be in column 14 and in all the following lines `xi` would be in column 8.

A procedure in gnuplot (without awk) would be the following:

1. plot the file into a dummy table. If line number is 1 (i.e. `($0==1)`) assign the values in column 2 `$2` and column 3 `$3` to `Ymin` and `Ymax`, respectively. Always, assign column value 8 `$8` to `Xmax`, so after plotting `Xmax` will contain the last value, here 5.4063.
2. then plot the file `with vectors` (skipping the first line) and use column 14 for the next line and column 8 for all the other lines as `xi` value.

After your comment this is probably more what you want.
You can get details from gnuplot help when typing `help <keyword>`, e.g. `help vectors`.

**Code:** (modified after comments)

```
### Extract values from file
reset session

FILE = 'tbExtractArrow.dat'

# extract Ymin, Ymax and Xmax
set table $Dummy
    plot FILE u ($0==1?(Ymin=$2,Ymax=$3):NaN,Xmax=$8) w table
unset table
print Ymin,Ymax,Xmax

# define formula for column to extract xi
myColumn(n) = n==0 ? 14 : 8

set xrange [0:Xmax]
set yrange[Ymin:Ymax]
set xtics ( "{/Symbol G}" 0.00000, "{/Times-New, F}" 0.27445, "{/Times-New Q}" 0.46775, "{/Times-New, Z}" 0.74220, "{/Symbol G}" 0.93550, "etc." 1.4) 

plot FILE skip 1 u (column(myColumn($0))):(Ymin):(0):(Ymax-Ymin) w vectors nohead lw 2 lc rgb "red" notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Dear theozh, this is very similar what I was looking for. But this would be my only gnuplot box. The actual data I will plot is from other file. What I am looking for can be seen on below google link (you can prefer lest top corner plot). The x-range would be [0:Xf] wher  Xf is last number of Xi that 5.4063 here. Also, instead of mentioning x-axis labels automatically, I will use  this set xtics  ( "{/Symbol G}" 0.00000, "{/Times-New, F}" 0.27445, "{/Times-New Q}" 0.46775, "{/Times-New, Z}" 0.74220, "{/Symbol G}" 0.93550, ) ........" (I will manage x-axis ticks).

Comment: We have different time zone thats why I could not reply in time.

Comment: aah, I forgot it. Here it goes:      https://www.google.com/search?q=phonon+band+structure&client=ubuntu&hs=Ca7&channel=fs&sxsrf=ACYBGNRaiJu2CNuFol1-mksXSLSjoJ-Gsw:1573060967815&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS_8jhjNblAhUx7HMBHT6wAkMQ_AUIESgB&biw=1853&bih=926

Comment: It worked for me. but one error still is there  Xmax seems not working                                       "plot.gnu", line 24: x range is invalid             . anyway  I can define Xmax with status option.
"

Comment: I will use my original file to plot after "plot FILE skip 1 u (column(myColumn($0))):(Ymin):(0):(Ymax-Ymin) w vectors nohead lw 2 lc rgb "red" notitle"  plot 'my_data.dat' u 1:2 wl lc 2 title "band"      This my_data.dat is having n lines parallel to x-axis with different different height and I want to make bottom three of them in different colors. Like in Figure (c) in below link  https://pubs.rsc.org/image/article/2018/ta/c8ta03150a/c8ta03150a-f5_hi-res.gif

Comment: if I don't have the actual data (or at least a description of the exact structure) and the actual full code, I just can make blind guesses.