# How to control colours for few starting n lines in gnuplut

Tags: gnuplot

I am having a two column file which contains data for n row. I want first few n starting lines with my required colours. Could you please tell me how to control the colours for first few lines in the below two column file for a gnuplot script?

```
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5970dd1edd1a5a56999b4df3510751c620191108072534/1d6477
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is a follow-up from your [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58336828/7295599). To plot the first three sections in different color us `column(-1)`. It is a pseudocolumn (see `help pseudocolumns`).

**Code:**

```
### plot first three datasets with different color
reset session

myColor(n) = n==0 ? 0xff0000 : n==1 ? 0x00ff00 : n==2 ? 0x0000ff : 0xcccccc

plot "plot_data.dat" u 1:2:(myColor(column(-1))) w l lc rgb var notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr. theozh. you are right. This is from my previous query. Thank you for suggesting "help pseudocolumns". Could you please tell me why you define four colours in the script while there are only three (n=0,1,2)? why there is an extra colour 0xcccccc. If I need to make a particular plot with a particular colour then I should insert  n==m ? "colour_type" , where m is the index of my plot.

Comment: red `0xff0000`, green `0x00ff00` and blue `0x0000ff` are for 0,1,2, respectively and grey `0xcccccc` otherwise. Check `help ternary`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. theozh. You are great. You always solve my complex issues.